# React To Laravel POST request throws error but API working fine With Postman

Tags: reactjs, laravel, axios

So I am trying to send a post request with the data about an announcement.
The data includes TITLE, TYPE, DESCRIPTION.
for backend I am using laravel with the following controller code.

```
class PostController extends Controller{
public function store(Request $request){
    $post = new Post;
    $post -> title = $request -> input('title');
    $post -> type = $request -> input('type');
    $post -> desc = $request -> input('desc');
    $post -> save();

    return response() -> json([
        'status'=> 200,
        'message' => 'Post Stored Successfully'
    ]);
}}
```

the Routing looks like following

`Route::Post('/addPost',[PostController::class, 'store'] );`

I am using the following component code in react to send the post request.

```
import axios from "axios";

import "./../styles/postEditor.css";

class PostEditor extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { type: "Announcement" };
    }

    state = {
        title: "",
        type: "",
        description: "",
    };

    handleInput = (e) => {
        this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    };

    savePost = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const res = await axios.post(
            "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/addPost",
            this.state
        );
        if (res.data.status === 200) {
            console.log(res.data.message);
            this.setState({ title: "", type: "", description: "" });
        }
    };
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="postEditor">
                <div className="editorTitle"> Create/Update Post</div>
                <form onSubmit={this.savePost}>
                    <div className="postForm">
                        <label className="top">Title:</label>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            name="title"
                            className="titleInput"
                            value={this.state.name}
                            onChange={this.handleInput}
                            placeholder="Enter the Title"
                            required
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div className="postForm">
                        <label>Type:</label>
                        <select
                            name="type"
                            className="form-control highlight"
                            value={this.state.type}
                            onChange={this.handleInput}
                            required
                        >
                            <option value="Technology">Technology</option>
                            <option value="Programming">Programming</option>
                            <option value="Design">Design</option>
                            <option value="Development">Development</option>
                            <option value="Creativity">Creativity</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div className="postForm">
                        <label>Description:</label>
                        <textarea
                            type="text"
                            name="description"
                            className="descInput"
                            value={this.state.desc}
                            onChange={this.handleInput}
                            placeholder="Write Something"
                            required
                        />
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" className="primary">
                        Submit
                    </button>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default PostEditor;
```

I keep getting the following errors

[image]

But when I send a post request with Postman everything seems to work fine on backend.

[image]

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with my browser sending OPTIONS request instead of POST and my laravel can't handle it while Postman sends POST request which is handled by the server.

Comment: Check your server log files to get more information on why the server is generating a `500` response. Also ensure that `CORS` and your `Authorization` header is configured correctly.

Comment: found the following string in logs
Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'desc' cannot be null

Comment: Therein lies your problem, and hopefully solution.  [:

Comment: `$post -> desc = $request -> input('desc'); ` needs to be ` $post -> desc = $request -> input('description'); ` its working now Thank you very much such a silly mistake